# jQuery change event on select isn't being triggered via other function changing selected attribute

Tags: jquery, multi-select

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="myID" name="myName">
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>                
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select')
    .change(function(){
        alert("Change Event Triggered On:" + $(this).attr("value"));
    })
```

That, as is, works. If I click an item in the multiselect, the alert is triggered.

However, when I 'select' an element from the select menu via jQuery like so:

```
$('#myOtherSelector')
    .click(function(){
        var $matchingOption = [goes and selects the specific OPTION to toggle]
        if ($matchingOption.attr("selected")){
            $matchingOption.removeAttr("selected")
        }else{
    $matchingOption.attr("selected","selected");
        }
    })
```

That script works in that it changes the SELECTED attribute and visually updates the option list, however the onchange event doesn't get triggered in that scenario.

Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing elements with code like that just doesn't trigger event handlers. You can do it yourself however:

```
else {
  $matchingOption.attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: hi pointy .. I have faced a problem that is quite similar to this question.. I have a multi select drop down i want to trigger onchange event . but i not trigger . how can i achieved this ? thanks in advance

Comment: With `<select>` elements, I've found that it's better to put "click" handlers on the `<option>` elements (or handle "click" when it bubbles up).  The way browsers generate "change" is usually not good for making dynamic changes from user activity on the `<select>`.