# How to add listeners on dom node removal, attribute modifications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, listener, dom-events

I want to add a listener on dom node add/remove and attribute modifications because I mostly generate dom elements dynamically for modules.

As you see in the picture below, `webkit` made it so it means these listeners exists.

[image]

If there is any jQuery functions please inform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can't expect Javascript to have a method or listener for anything which webkits developer tools can do. Its a buildin debugger and console which possibilites go way beyond.

However, there are the such called *Mutation Events* available, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events)

A typical call would look like

```
document.getElementsById( 'foo' ).addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function( e ) {
}, false);
```

which would fire on any attribute change from the *Node* with the id *foo*. One word of caution, the *Mutation Events* are deprecated and might not be available in the current form in the future.

Comment: +1. Might be worth mentioning that the API that replaces DOM mutation events is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver). Attribute changes are still covered by the new API. Also, DOM mutation events are not supported in IE <= 8.

Answer (score 0):

For attribute change events, you could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321438/382982).

```
$el.on('attribute:change', function () {...});
$el.attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('attribute:change');
```

For add/remove events, you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200886/382982):

```
(function() {
    var ev = new $.Event('remove'),
    orig = $.fn.remove;

    $.fn.remove = function() {
        $(this).trigger(ev);
        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
```